# why don't we use sigma-delta based fractional-N PLL in high speed SerDes application?

Tags: analog

I was always wondering if there is any particular reason to avoid using sigma-delta based fractional-N PLL in high speed SerDes application (+ 10 Gbps SerDes)

Can anyone answer my simple & stupid question here?

I was not able to find answer for this question online...

Comment: This is far too vague. Do you think that anyone IS avoiding it? Do you think that there's any particular reason TO use it? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Often a SerDes has to do CDR ("clock recovery from data"), rather than generating a serial clock from a lower-frequency reference. The PLL control for CDR is somewhat cruder than for a frequency multiplier PLL.  And if a reference clock is used, the SerDes designer can just tell user to provide an integer divided clock, saving on the extra die area that would be needed to support fractional-N.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sigma delta PLLs when your generated ratio is 'big number' rationally related to your reference, so millions or more.

With SERDES, even with 64/65 coding, the required rates are 'small number' rational, and your PLL can use simple integer ratios.